# Configure startup programs for a user AD-wide

Tags: windows-7, login, active-directory

Sorry if this has been asked before, neither the search feature here, or Google was of any help.

I'd like to configure startup programs for my own AD user that run whenever I login on any computer in the domain. So far I've only found ways to configure programs for a user on a single PC, or for all users on one PC. I'd like it to affect all computers in the domain, but only run the program if I login (the programs are present on a network share). Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Write a script that is executed that what is described in this [article](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/q-how-do-i-add-item-start-menu-all-users-windows-7-and-windows-vista)

Comment: Yes it's possible and pretty easy via Group Policy -- if you're the admin of the AD.  Are you?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes I am. Please guide me :)

Answer (score 1):

- Log onto a Windows AD DC server for the domain (assuming Windows Server 2008 or newer).
- Create a new Group Policy object (GPO) (use the [Group Policy Management Console](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753298.aspx)).
- Modify the GPO's scope by [using a Security Filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc752992.aspx) so that only your user account is affected by the polices in this GPO (GPMC -> Scope Tab -> Security Filtering; remove all existing users and groups, add your user account).
- Edit said GPO to add you logon script(s). (User Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> Logon).
- Apply the GPO to an [Organization Unit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758565(v=ws.10).aspx) (OU) that affects all computers (or target the root of the domain).

Comment: If you're using User Configuration settings, the GPO needs to be applied to the users OU.

Comment: Just to be a pedant, you shouldn't really be using an interactive logon to the DC if it can be avoided. Instead install RSAT on a workstation and use that to run your otherwise entirely correct steps.